# What "island" is Elastigirl referring to?

Tags: incredibles-2

In Scifi action movie [Incredibles 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incredibles_2), Violet Parr is arguing with her parents about saving the world:

> Violet Parr: You said things were different now.
>
> Elastigirl: And they were, on **the island**.
>
> Violet Parr: But I didn't mean that from now on...
>
> Elastigirl: So now, we've gotta go back to never  using our powers.

What "island" is Elastigirl referring to?

Comment: related: [Do I need to see The Incredibles to understand Incredibles 2?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95878/do-i-need-to-see-the-incredibles-to-understand-incredibles-2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She is referring to [Nomanisan Island](https://pixar.fandom.com/wiki/Nomanisan_Island), Syndrome's lair from the previous Incredibles film.

The line is a callback to her speech to Violet.

> **Helen:** *Shh. It isn’t your fault. **It wasn’t fair for me to suddenly ask so much of you. But things are different now.** And doubt is a luxury we can’t afford anymore, sweetie. You have more power than you realize. Don’t think. And don’t worry. lf the time comes, you’ll know what to do. It’s in your blood.*